# How do I switch to a process that's running to see the output?

Tags: command-line

I have a process that I run on my web server but sometimes my ssh into the machine gets disconnected so I miss seeing some of the output. If I log back in, I can see it running using `ps` yet I want to switch to it to see the output.

Comment: You will want to run it in a terminal multiplexer such as `screen` or `tmux` - see for example [recover ssh session connection](https://askubuntu.com/a/821741/178692)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem should be described as "How to reconnect to lost session". This was discussed for example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/19634/how-to-reconnect-to-a-disconnected-ssh-session), with answer:

> Try to set ClientAliveInterval (e.g. 60) and TCPKeepAlive (yes or no) to appropriate values on the serverside sshd.conf .
>
> This should keep your session alive even if the connection gets lost for minutes.