# Manage the dotnet process; detach, reattach and view output

Tags: process, webserver, background-process

On my **Ubuntu Server** I run the command `dotnet myapplication.dll` to start an application. It subsequently displays a steady stream of output logging to the screen.

I would like to be able to perform this action, disconnect from the process, perform some other tasks, and then re-establish the same session/output as I was originally viewing.

Since Ubuntu is a first class multitasking operating system, I assume this is possible, maybe through the use of `ps`, `pstree`, `pgrep`, `pkill`, `lsof`, `top`, `nice`, `renice` or some other similar commands.

I do understand a log file and `tail` would be a more optimal solution, but this is what I have to work with at the moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recover ssh session connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821724/recover-ssh-session-connection)

Comment: No. I am asking how to reconnect to a dot net process. Completely unrelated to SSH.

Comment: You could do that using reptyr, but it's far simpler to use screen or tmux sessions. Listing random process management commands without understanding what they do doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon doing some reading, I shortly came to the realization that what I was describing was `systemd`.